# Python - How to arrange multiple histograms in a grid

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

The following code read each row from a numpy ndarray and create multiple histograms on the same figure:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))
fontP = FontProperties()
fontP.set_size('small')
for f in eval_list:
    local_id = getIndexByIdentifier(f)
    temp_sim = total_sim[local_id,:]
    c=np.random.rand(3,1)
    ax.hist(temp_sim, 10, ec=c, fc='none', lw=1.5, histtype='step', label=f)
    ax.legend(loc="upper left", bbox_to_anchor=(1.1,1.1),prop = fontP)
```

[image]

Instead of including all histograms in one plot, how can I arrange them in a grid 5 x 5?

Here is an updated code:

```
#Plot indvidual Histograms
SIZE = 10
all_data=[]
for f in eval_list:
    local_id = getIndexByIdentifier(f)
    temp_sim = total_sim[local_id,:]
    all_data.append(temp_sim)

# create grid 10x10    
fi, axi = plt.subplots(SIZE, SIZE,figsize=(50,50))
for idx, data in enumerate(all_data):
    x = idx % SIZE
    y = idx // SIZE
    axi[y, x].hist(data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use different `ax` to put plot in different "cell" in "grid"

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

SIZE = 5

# random data
all_data = []
for x in range(SIZE*SIZE):
    all_data.append([ random.randint(0,10) for _ in range(10) ])

# create grid 5x5    
f, ax = plt.subplots(SIZE, SIZE)

# put data in different cell
for idx, data in enumerate(all_data):
    x = idx % SIZE
    y = idx // SIZE
    ax[y, x].hist(data)

plt.show()
```

[image]