# Plotting two datasets from different folders on one plot

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, plot

I have two folders with similar number of files: `maindirNo` and `maindirWith`. I'm trying to plot each pair of similar files from folders on one plot:

```
for i in [maindirNo, maindirWith]:
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(i):
    for fil in files:
        if 'output.rsv' in fil:
            df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(i, fil), skiprows = 9, delimiter = r'\s+', header = None)
            df['SIMULATEDm'] = mergedlevels
            df['OBSERVEDm'] = df_observed['OBSERVEDm']
            df['date'] = pd.date_range('1/1991','12/2040', freq='MS')
            if i == maindirNo:
                plt.plot(df['date'], df['SIMULATEDm'], 'b', label='No outlet')
            if i == maindirWith:
                plt.plot(df['date'], df['SIMULATEDm'], 'r', label='With outlet')
            plt.legend(loc = 'lower right')
            plt.savefig('C:/Users/sgulbin/Desktop/AGU_Conf/plots/%s.jpg' %fil)
            plt.close()
```

The problem is that I either have all datesets plotted on one plot, or one plot for each file (I need two datasets on one plot). I assume I can append output to an empty dataframe and then plot it, but is there a simplest way to plot them through the loop?

P.S. I know there are kind of similar questions to this, but not exactly.

Comment: `pandas` use `matplotlib` which returns  `fig` and `ax` when you use `subplots()` to create many plots and then you can use `ax` to choose  plot for drawing line - `ax[0].plot()`, `ax[1].plot()`. ie. http://stackoverflow.com/a/40761336/1832058

Comment: I can't see the pairs of similar files in your code. How do you know that whether two files are similar or not if you only look at them one by one?

Answer (score 0):

`pandas` uses `matplotlib` which gives `fig` and `ax` when you create many plots. ie. 5 plots in one column

```
 fig, ax = plt.subplots(5, 1)
```

and then you can use `ax[0]`, `a[1]` to choose plot for drawed line.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import random

SIZE = 5

# create grid 5x1
fig, ax = plt.subplots(SIZE, 1)

# --- first folder --- blue ---

for idx in range(SIZE):

    # dataframe with random data as example
    df = pd.DataFrame([ random.randint(0,10) for _ in range(10) ])

    # draw it
    ax[idx].plot(df, 'b')

# --- second folder --- red ---

for idx in range(SIZE):

    # dataframe with random data as example
    df = pd.DataFrame([ random.randint(0,10) for _ in range(10) ])

    # draw it
    ax[idx].plot(df, 'r')

plt.show()
```

[image]